# Script to paste a specific string into a text field with a hotkey

Tags: linux, scripting, paste, shortcut, gnome

I am trying to find a way to paste a predefined string upon entering a specific keyboard sequence, on any app.

For example if I have to paste an url or a password into a field, I can have said password in a hidden script and when I press, say, [ctrl] + [5], it would write "example123" on the text field where my cursor is.

Ideally without copying to the clipboard (I'd prefer keeping what I have on my clipboard and also avoiding to paste a password or such by mistake elsewhere).

I have tried every solution I've found so far that include xclip, xdotool and xvkdb. All of them either do not work or are really inconsistent: They only paste the string sometimes, and when they do, it's usually only part of the string ("ample123" instead of "example123").

I thought of using compose key, which I heavily use anyway to write in french on an us keyboard, but it seems it only supports 1 character sequences, as nothing is printed when I modify my .XCompose to include custom output sequences of len > 1.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome as a DE. Ideally something that also works when logging back (like compose keys).

Answer (score 0):

You need to walk the Document Object Model for either Gnome or your web-page. My concern is that with a desktop script you wont be able to access the web page because you will need to be able to establish a target to send string to. I see in your question that you tried using using "x{tool-name}" to grab the text field element. Delivering the sting really isn't the problem. The problem is getting the GUI element of text box pragmatically. The easiest way to get access to this in a user loaded web-page is with [WebExtensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) which is how to make extensions for most modern browsers. Otherwise, if you can get away with only having access to Gnome's GUI I would try [LDTP](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org), it's a library used for testing, but it looks like it can be used for automation too.

For keyboard shortcuts:
It really shouldn't matter what the script is doing to how you want to activate it. I would just go to Gnome/Settings/Keyboard and set the path to where I saved the script to be the Command. If you go the WebExtension route, you will want to build the shortcut into your extension.